# Labeling different figures, font,size MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure

**I am trying to basically copy this graph for practice for my final coming up but I don't understand how to change the font,size or labeling the axis. Simply put, I need to replicate this graph exactly from my code. I need the font to be times new roman and size 18 with a marker size of 8. How would I format my code into this?**
[image]

**This is my code:**

```
clear
clc

x = linspace(0,2);
y1 = sin(2*pi*x);
y2 = exp(-0.5*2*pi*x).*sin(2*pi*x);


figure
subplot(2,1,1);
hPlot1 = plot(x,y1,'rs');
ylabel('f(t)')
set(gca,'YLim',[-1 2],'YTick',-1:1:2,'XTick',0:.5:2)

subplot(2,1,2);
hPlot2 = plot(x,y2,'k*');
xlabel('Time(s)')
ylabel('g(t)')
set(gca,'YLim',[-0.2,0.6],'YTick',[-0.2,0,0.2,0.4,0.6],'XTick',0:.5:2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `xlabel('Time(s)')` by:

```
xlabel('Time(s)','FontName','TimesNewRoman','FontSize',18)
```

and do the same for `ylabel`.

For the marker size, replace `hPlot1 = plot(x,y1,'rs');` by

```
hPlot1 = plot(x,y1,'r-',x(1:5:end),y1(1:5:end),'ks','MarkerSize',8);
```

and the same for the other plot.

Finally, you can add text to the figure using the `text` function, e.g.:

```
text(0.5,1.5,'Harmonic force f(t) = sin(\omega t)')
```

Again, you can change the font size and font name, as with `xlabel` and `ylabel`.

Comment: Hey thanks!! The graph and all is correct but for some reason the text isn't showing up on my MATLAB R2014a but it doesnt appear when using the lab computers with run Linux and matlab 2013. Ps I am running windows 8 and the command says the "unable to interpret latex"

Comment: You probably need to specify the interpreter as `latex`: `text(0.5,1.5,'Harmonic force f(t) = sin(\omega t)','interpreter','latex')`

Answer (score 4):

The code below:

```
%// x = linspace(0,2); %// changed that to respect where the markers are on your example figure 
x = 0:0.1:2 ; 
y1 = sin(2*pi*x);
y2 = exp(-0.5*2*pi*x).*sin(2*pi*x);

figure
h.axtop = subplot(2,1,1) ;
h.plottop = plot(x,y1,'LineStyle','-','Color','r', ...
                    'Marker','s', ...
                    'MarkerEdgeColor','k', ...
                    'MarkerFaceColor','none', ...
                    'MarkerSize',8) ;
set(gca,'YLim',[-1 2],'YTick',-1:1:2,'XTick',0:.5:2)
h.ylbl(1) = ylabel('\itf(t)') ;     %// label is set in "italic" mode with the '\it' tag at the beginning

h.axbot = subplot(2,1,2);
h.plotbot = plot(x,y2,'-ks', ...
                    'Marker','*', ...
                    'MarkerEdgeColor','r', ...
                    'MarkerSize',8) ;
set(gca,'YLim',[-0.2,0.6],'YTick',[-0.2,0,0.2,0.4,0.6],'XTick',0:.5:2)
h.xlbl(1) = xlabel('Time(s)') ;
h.ylbl(2) = ylabel('\itg(t)') ;     %// label is set in "italic" mode with the '\it' tag at the beginning

%// create the "text" annotations
h.txttop = text(0.5,1.5, 'Harmonic force \itf(t)=sin(\omegat)' , 'Parent',h.axtop ) ;                   %// note the 'parent' property set to the TOP axes
h.txtbot = text(0.5,0.3, 'Forced response \itg(t)=e^{\zeta\omegat} sin(\omegat)' , 'Parent',h.axbot ) ; %// note the 'parent' property set to the BOTTOM axes

%// set the common properties for all text objects in one go
set( [h.xlbl h.ylbl h.txttop h.txtbot] , 'FontName','Times New Roman' , 'FontSize',18)
```

will produce the following figure:
[image: figure]

note how the handle of the graphic object were saved and re-used to set properties later on. If multiple graphic object (even different) have the same property, it is possible to assign this property to all the graphic object in one go.

Look at the Matlab [`text`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html?refresh=true) function documentation for more detail on how to place annotations on your figure.